how do I set up a jupyter notebook that will run dash-leaflet, dash_table
I had to add in "dash-leaflet" to my project this week but Pylance can't find it.
the auto complete can see dash_leaflet but it's still not found when I click on either of the suggestions

I've tried adding the interpreter path to the settings.json
(note this settings.json isn't inside a .vscode folder) I saw from another thread that gets created when you change interpreters, I think this should apply to all environments no?)

and importing sys and using sys.path.append(/file/path)
using $which python and python3 and brew info to find different file paths to try

The one thing that sort of worked was moving dash-leaflet from it's location in /brew/ to the bin in my conda environment. It only partly works, because I have to go into dash-leaflet create an .ipynb file, and then Pylance will import dash_leaflet, but when I start jupyter lab and try to run the cell, I get an import error on dash_table.

I then $cd dash-leaflet and $jupyter lab but when I run the cell I get this. (dash_table works in my other files located in the same place I activate my conda env)

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 7
      5 from dash import dcc, html
      6 import plotly.express as px
----> 7 import dash_table
      8 from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
     10 from dash import dash_table

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_table'

I've also tried moving it again to put it in the same dir that I activate my conda ve from and the bin thats above the conda > env > mien > bin. ( I used mv /old/path /new/path) and tried it with -r but it doesn't move.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

it's not really a coding question, it's a file structure question,... the only code I could provide would be the "import dash_leaflet" with pylance yellow squiggle under it. I'll edit but I don't see how that helps

Please provide textual information as text. That includes the erroring code, sys.path.appends/whichs you tried, the JSON settings, and the error message. Use the formatting tools like code formatting. The screenshots are fine to illustrate and provide additional context though, like the red squiggle under dash_leaflet. Speaking of that, the settings.json you're talking about is your user config, meaning it applies to all environments unless it's overridden.

Is the second-last screenshot the output from ls? It'd be good to make that explicit

I'm not familiar with Dash, so IDK if there are any special procedures, but FWIW, normally you'd set up a project environment and install libraries there, while the screenshots show that you're using a base env. Docs here: Using Python Environments in Visual Studio Code If I'm right, then you absolutely don't need to manually copy anything or adjust sys.path. It also seems like you're confusing executable files (in a bin/ folder) with library files (in a lib/ folder).

edited again, I don't want to sound argumentative, I truly want help with this,... but it's not a coding problem that someone else will be able to copy paste my code to see if they can get it to work,... (I assume that's the reason to provide code blocks)

for previous weeks, I had trouble with plotly, and dash_table,... I ended up getting rid of my entire python env and starting over in a conda env and that worked. I'm wondering if my issues have anything to do with the fact that dash-leaflet isn't a forge install? I had to pip install it, and when I go find it I can cd into dash-leaflet unlike my other imports and run files from inside the folder.

@BrianFulton Of course. I didn't say it was a debugging problem, just that we want to see the actual text. It's explained in the link, but to be brief: "copy and paste any other textual data relevant to the question - such as commands typed at a terminal prompt, errors, logs, configuration, or project files ... reasons: Images cannot be interpreted by screen readers, making them completely inaccessible for users with visual impairments. [etc.]" One other thing is, if I wanted to talk about one of those paths, I'd have to manually retype it.

I'm using oh-my-zsh with powerlevel10k configuration, the environment is displayed bottom right I named it "condave" so it is active while I have been installing and running files

@BrianFulton I'm talking about VSCode, in the status bar (blue), bottom right: {'base': conda}. Also top right in the Jupyter screenshot: base

@wjandrea can you change a comment, or add a new response as an answer so I can give you the solution check. After you explained about where is says 'base' I clicked the "base(Python 3.11.7)" in the top right and cycled through the kernel options. I found that one of them recognized dash_leaflet, it still didn't see the other dash modules but using the file path from that kernel in the sys.path.append was the fix and everything is running in my lab now. Thank you for your time!

@BrianFulton Well, that's not quite what I had in mind, but if it works for you, great! I'm fine with just getting a mention in your answer :)

Thank you for the link to VS code docs,.. that helps a lot. I have been using the VE folder as a workspace, which it specifically says not to do >.<

the fix was finding the proper file path for dash-leaflet

using the kernel selection option in vs code where it says base(Python 3.11.7) cycling through different kernels, changed pylance import errors.
adding the kernel path that didn't show the error with sys.path.append(path) fixed all imports.
thanks to
wjandrea

for getting me on the right path
